# How to add weight initialization stategy to tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Ofcourse , I know how to initialize weights for use by my specific project , using numpy etc , but I was wondering how I can add the init strategy to tensor flow , that is I wanted to contribute to the project . Which file has the implementations of init strategies like Xavier so that I can add He et al to it ? 
Also if I wanted to add l-BFGS to the package , where would I even start looking ?

Any pointers are deeply appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the implementation for Xavier initialization here.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/6b1d4fd8090d44d20fdadabf06f1a9b178c3d80c/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/initializers.py#L31